# Use SQL Service Broker to Decouple Service From Database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, architecture, service-broker

I'm looking at putting together a fairly straight-forward WCF-based service, and I have a question about how best to decouple it from the database.

**Background**: The service I'm going to be implementing is highly critical, geographically distributed, and needs to be as available as possible through a disaster or database failure. The business logic is pretty simple; it receives events from an external source, maintains a state table, and broadcasts processed updates to connected clients. I'm replacing a service that currently handles 400-600 incoming events per second, and approximately 10-20 concurrently connected clients. There will be multiple instances of the service running in multiple locations across the US. All instances host the same state data and share events. There is one instance of a master (SQL Server 2008) database in one location.

**Challenge**: I've built a number of applications similar to this in the past, and I have most of the architectural hurdles behind me. But there's one challenge I've come across to which I can't help but imagine there's a better solution: in my design, the database (MSSQL) is used **only** for persistence; the database is only read when the first instance of the service starts and for offline reporting. During normal operation, the application only ever writes historical data to the DB.

To fully decouple the application from the database, in the past I've used SQL Service Broker: On each server running the service, I install an instance of SQL Server Express that essentially just acts as a queue for Service Broker messages to the core (SSB "target") database. In normal operating conditions, the application executes all its SQL operations against the local instance, which queues/forwards them to the target DB via SSB. This works pretty well, and to be honest I'm fairly happy with it... As long as the local instance of SQL Server Express is up, the application will obviously stay unaware of problems at the target DB, network issues between it and the target DB, etc., and it's highly survivable in the case of a localized disaster. It's easy to monitor, not too horribly ugly to set up, and it's all supported. In short, it works, and I'm content to live with it if I have to.

But it strikes me as a bit of a kludge. It feels like there should a better way to do that.

Obviously one option is to just queue the database operations in process. I don't like that because if I'm going to decouple things at all, I'd prefer to really decouple and keep my application itself as far away from the DB as possible. I could also write a Data Service that queues these operations... I actually briefly started down that path before thinking to myself, "Wait, isn't this what SSB already does?"

Due to unchangeable external constraints, a more robust/HA SQL Server architecture is not an option. I've been given my one DB cluster and that's that.

So I'm open to just about any thoughts and/or criticisms. Is there something obvious I'm missing? This feels like the kind of thing where there could be something stone-simple I've just somehow overlooked (though not for lack of searching.) Am I making some kind of wider architectural mistake here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion is obviously biased, but for the record I can point to several fairly big projects that do (or did) it the same way, like [High volumn contiguos real Time ETL](http://rusanu.com/2010/06/11/high-volume-contiguos-real-time-audit/), [March Madness on Demand](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rdoherty/archive/2009/03/13/march-madness-on-demand.aspx) or [MySpace SQL Server Service Broker](http://www.slideshare.net/markginnebaugh/myspace-sql-server-service-broker-oct-2009).

But several things changed in later years, and the primary change is the rise of PaaS offerings. Today you can have a highly available, scalable database and messaging platform, eg. [SQL Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/data-management/) and [Azure Queues/Azure Service Buss](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx). Or [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) and [SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) if you're willing to step outside SQL/ACID. Arguably, the price point of a park of SQL Express instances pushing to a central SQL Server Standard Edition  will be lower than a PaaS solution, but it will be hard to beat the PaaS in terms of availability, free maintenance and scale on-demand.

So aside from the PaaS oint of view above, I would argue that the solution you have is superior to pretty much anything else the MS stack has. WCF is sure easy to program against, unless you have the anti-SOAP fever, but has basically 0 (zero) to offer in terms of availability/reliability. Your process is gone === your data is gone, end of story. WCf over MSMQ is 'WCF' just in name, the programming model of queue channels is miles away from the http/net binding WCF programming model. And MSMQ has little to stand up agains Service Broker (aside from ubiquity). but then again, as you probably know, I am really biased in my opinion...

Comment: Thanks for the input, @remus-rusanu. (BTW, your site was **hugely** helpful to me in originally getting going with SSB. So thanks for that too!) 

PaaS isn't really an option due to policy constraints within which I have to work, though of course that would make a lot of these concerns disappear. Like I said, I think the solution I've used in situations like this before, while a bit clunky, is certainly workable... It just seems like there's one extra moving part in there (SQL Express) that I should somehow be able to do away with. But perhaps not and I'm better off than I think!

Comment: Express gives you durable storage *and* reliable messaging. Quite hard to replace...